# what is the difference between read and read and execute permission

Tags: windows-server-2008

My question is about the permission we set in a security group .
how to sset permissions and what is the difference between read and read and execute permission.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will answer your question: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

In short, windows permissions vary based on whether the target is a folder or a file. The tables in this explain it in detail. The information is dated but for the most part this should still be intact.

This is a bit more up to date and applies now but a bit more complicated.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530(v=ws.10).aspx